# EWS Contracts Search via XML

Tags: xml, soap, exchangewebservices

I want to pull back contacts via EWS where BusinessPhone or MobilePhone exists (under PhoneNumbers) - see example Contact info

```
<Contact>
    <ItemId Id="XX2ASDFR"/>
    <PhoneNumbers>
        <Entry Key="MobilePhone">(02)9999-8888</Entry>
    </PhoneNumbers>
    <Surname>Test</Surname>
</Contact>
```

My search critera exists of the following

```
<Restriction>
<t:Or>
<t:Exists>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhoneNumbers" FieldURI="BusinessPhone" />
</t:Exists>
<t:Exists>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhoneNumbers" FieldURI="MobilePhone" />
</t:Exists>
</t:Or>
</Restriction>
```

How does one search on nested fields?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Extended property instead of the Strongly Typed version eg for BusinessPhone use PidTagBusinessTelephoneNumber https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839937(v=office.12).aspx eg

```
       <m:Restriction>
      <t:IsEqualTo>
        <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="14856" PropertyType="String" />
        <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          <t:Constant Value="332332232" />
        </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
      </t:IsEqualTo>
    </m:Restriction>
```

Comment: I dont want it equal to anything. I want to make sure the property exists

Comment: Thats just a working example of using the property you just need to replace IndexedFieldURI  with ExtendedFieldURI in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
<Restriction>
<t:Or>
    <t:Exists>
        <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhoneNumber" FieldIndex="BusinessPhone" />
    </t:Exists>
    <t:Exists>
        <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhoneNumber" FieldIndex="MobilePhone" />
    </t:Exists>
</t:Or>
</Restriction>
```